# How do I make a python window always be on bottom?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

How do I make a python window always be on bottom?

Comment: which "bottom"? In stacking order, or at the bottom of the screen? And what do you mean by "always"? Do you mean you want to prevent the user from moving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about Tkinter, you can use:

```
 window.geometry('300x200-5+40')
```

Where the 300x200 is the size, and -5+40 is the positioning offsets.